# Docker private registry - Method not allowed 405

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to create private registry for docker and I'm relying on [instructions given](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) on the docker site. I have a seperate linux box where this registry is installed, then I'm trying to push my images from local(osx box with docker toolbox). I keep on getting 405 from registry server. I'm quite new to docker. I was hoping the default basic configuration to work without much trouble.

### configuration

Latest docker toolbox. 
Latest registry installation. 
I only changes the TLS configuration to post the request over http.

### Error

```
    The push refers to a repository [192.168.1.98:5000/complete] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Error: Status 405 trying to push repository complete: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>\n<p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /v1/repositories/complete/.</p>\n</body></html>\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [doc mentions](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/bfd1f423c5c0c94afbafc11e57376f48ac52554a/docs/spec/api.md#on-failure-not-allowed)

```
405 Method Not Allowed
```

> Manifest put is not allowed because the registry is configured as a pull-through cache or for some other reason

(like [a read-only mode](https://github.com/docker/distribution/pull/827))

> UNSUPPORTED: The operation was unsupported due to a missing implementation or invalid set of parameters.

The same doc uses urls which include /v2, not like the one used in the question (`/v1/repositories/complete`)

[The instructions](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#load-balancing-considerations) include:

> Getting the headers correct is very important. For all responses to any request under the “`/v2/`” url space, the `Docker-Distribution-API-Version` header should be set to the value “`registry/2.0`”, even for a `4xx` response

Make sure you are running a v2 registry image (which is now [docker distribution](https://github.com/docker/distribution))

---

The [OP Charith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718149/charith) actually found [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797419/docker-private-registry-method-not-allowed-405/33798226#comment55401112_33798226):

> mistake in port forwarding on the registry host: **The 5000 port was servicing from another server**.
>   I've switched to an available port and everything started working.

Comment: Apologies for my limited knowledge on this. I'm sure I've installed registry V2 version on registry host box. And it works fine within that box itself (push and pull). Now I'm trying to push images from my client box and it's failing. For client box I'm using latest docker tool box installation for osx and API calls being made out of this client box, i guess problem lies around client installation. Is there anyway to upgrade ToolBox to use V2 api instead of V1?

Comment: Hi It was my bad. Stupid mistake in port forwarding on the registry host. The 5000 port was servicing from another server. I've switched to an available port and everything started working. Thanks heaps for insight given though.

Comment: @Charith Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.